# How to center the textview horizontally and vertically in android

Tags: android, textview, center

How to **center** the `TextView` horizontally and vertically in android. I tried using `gravity:center`. But text is displayed in the `center vertically`. I want it to be displayed horizontally too. How to do that.

**Here is my code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.display.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_mesaage"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:onClick="displaym"/>   
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/display_mes"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try using a `RelativeLayout`. It will allow you to center in parent.

Comment: I tried it..But it overlaps my button and edit text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout. Then for your TextView, try

```
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/display_mes"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

This usually works for me.

Comment: It works. But my button overlaps with edit Text field. What orientation should i give for the button to bring it to the left/below of edit text field.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you sir...but it worked for me..i used relative layout and used android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 3):

Can you use: "center_horizontal|center_vertical"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it up dynamically using:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Or just

`textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"`

As `android:gravity` affects the contents of the view you have, while the property `android:layout_gravity="center"` shall center the whole `view` layout according to the parent. So for a text in a `textView` to be centered use

```
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/display_mes"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

It because main `LinearLayout` **orientation** is `horizontal` so that happen try like below code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.display.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_mesaage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="displaym"
            android:text="send" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_mes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="textview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OR**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.display.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_mesaage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_mesaage"
        android:onClick="displaym"
        android:text="send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_mes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="textview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you..It worked for me...Also is it possible to put a linear layout inside a relative layout?

Comment: @sangeetha yes it is possible.

Comment: I'm a beginner in android. I started learning from developer.android.com. But i'm nt able to follow it. So thought of developing some simple apps so that i learn while doing. Can suggest me some simple apps,?

Comment: which kind of app do you want to implement@sangeetha??

Comment: @sangeetha Refer these two like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html and http://androidexample.com/ there are so much simple examples are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your `LinearLayout` with a `RelativLayout` and slightly change the layout parameters on the `LinearLayout`, something like below suggestion:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:Android="..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        ... 

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will ensure the internal relation between your buttons and text views are unchanged, since they are still wrapped by the `LinearLayout`, which in turn isn't filling the screen any more, hence, it can be centered within its new parent; the `RelativeLayout`.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```